# Enable Indic fonts on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, fonts

I wish to enable Indic fonts on my MacBook running OS X 10.6.

I found some OS X support pages which said that some Indic fonts are enabled by default in 10.4, but I've not been able to find any such page for 10.6.

Can I enable these somehow or will I need to install third-party fonts?

Comment: There are e.g. Gujarati and Devanagari character lists in Character Palette (*Character Viewer*), provided by fonts like *Gujarati MT*. There are matching input types available in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources*. What is it you're missing? There's no need to "enable fonts", they're just there. (Wikipedia says these are alphabets from India, but I have no knowledge there, so I might be wrong)

Comment: If you don't have these fonts: Pre-10.7 versions of OS X allowed some customization during setup. It's possible the fonts were deselected. In that case, insert the OS X DVD and install them.

Comment: What I mean is that all I see is unicode boxes when I go to a hindi language site. One could assume that some sites are malfunctioning, but all of them, including google?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Mine is a corporate laptop, so dont have an installation disc.

Comment: Might [this](http://www.mohanbn.com/mac-osx-and-indic-fonts/) help?

Comment: Check the Font Book application whether you have font for these Indic alphabets installed.

Comment: @DanielBeck : Have done so, couldn't find the fonts. (Checked in /library/fonts and /system/library/fonts too). So I assume that the problem is that my installation does not have the optional package required for these fonts. Any idea how can I install this package without an installation disc?

Comment: No. You're supposed to have the disk. You should probably ask IT for help.